# When saved, WordPress editor automatically adds "rel=nofollow" to every external link

Tags: wordpress, plugins, editor, wordpress-gutenberg, nofollow

currently I'm running into this issue, where external links are automatically set to no-follow by WordPress. As of now I wasn't able to detect the source of this behaviour.

The page uses the Classic Editor (v1.6.2) Plugin - however, the problem still occurs without the use of this Plugin.

There are a bunch of other plugins installed but those are not directly involved with the post editin feature of WordPress. Are there any clues which might cause this issue?

If you need any information I can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Which other Plugins are you using?

Are you maybe using RankMath or another SEO Plugin?
These have a setting to make all external links with "rel=nofollow". You would need to deactivate this or add an exceptions for specific domains.

Check the settings.

Comment: Check your SEO Plugin, there is a setting for all external links, for rank math you can go to general settings and you'll see the settings there

Comment: I deactivated every Plugin and changed the Theme to Wordpress Default Theme, however the problem still occurs. Could it be some sort of global settings via Server or .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes, that could also be. Do you have another Website to compare? Btw. how exactly do you know that you get a nofollow. Make a screenshot.

Comment: It's now resolved by simply installing the newest version of WordPress. I can't tell why, maybe the older version of WP (v6.0.3.) somehow caused an issue. The Editor always added "rel=nofollow" to an external link after saving - so after saving it the second time it would add another rel=nofollow tag and so on - very weird behaviour

Comment: Did you try to change the no to do? Such as rel="dofollow"

Comment: Yes, it simply added another rel with "nofollow" attribute.

Comment: The problem occured again - I deactivated every plugin and switched back to a standard theme but I can"t resolve it. Reinstalling WordPress doesnt work either.